# why is this update statement not updating?

Tags: mysql

I have the following update statement:

```
update TradingEntityTemp tet
set tet.TypeId = (select ct.Id from CustomerType ct where ct.Name = tet.Name)
```

MySQL Workbench outputs the following info:

> "0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 29  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0"

"29" represents the rowcount in TradingEntityTemp.  Any idea why TradingEntityTemp.TypeId isn't getting updated via this update statement?

Comment: 0 rows affected mean 0 raws has changed, so all matched rows already have actual dats

Comment: TradingEntityTemp.TypeId values are all still NULL when I select * from TradingEntityTemp after running the UPDATE statement

Comment: And you have rows in the `CustomerType` table, that has values corresponding the names in `TradingEntityTemp`?

Comment: If you see NULLs in updated table, so you have not matched record in CustomerType table.

Answer (score 1):

Resulting message inform 0 rows affected mean all rows already have actual data and has not changed. 
In any case I recommend to change your query to more effective, using join condition:

```
update 
    TradingEntityTemp tet
join CustomerType ct
    on ct.Name = tet.Name
set 
    tet.TypeId = ct.Id;
```